# Dockerfile issues

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Hi I got a project with a dockerfile, and I am trying to build the dockerfile to run the project in the environment it was created but I seem to get an error at step 5 of the build and when I look at the dockerfile I find the code a bit strange/I dont understand it at that point.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.10-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/app

# Install Node packages
COPY package.json package.json

RUN apk install git \

  && npm i \
  && apk del .gyp\
  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
  && apk del git

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
#COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

# Expose port
EXPOSE 88

#ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Step 5/8 : RUN apk install git   && npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*   && apk del git
 ---> Running in 251259cdb8a2
apk-tools 2.7.5, compiled for x86_64.
```

Then I get a bunch of text which resembles what you get if you type -help on something and then at the end i get:

```
This apk has coffee making abilities.
The command '/bin/sh -c apk install git   && npm i   && apk del .gyp  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*   && apk del git' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This seems to be the problematic part:

```
RUN apk install git \
  && npm i \
  && apk del .gyp\
  && mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
  && apk del git
```

Comment: You could try to run these command one by one in the `node:8.10-alpine` container, and see where it fails.

Comment: Probably should be "apk del .gyp \" (notice missing space before the backslash)

Comment: It definitely seems to be failing from RUN apk install git \ and all the && parts, how do i open just the alpine conatiner ??

Comment: Just run `docker run -it node:8.10-alpine bash` or `docker run -it node:8.10-alpine sh` if it uses sh instead of bash

Comment: ok I did add a bit more error info where it shows what step it gets stuck on though, so I already know where it gets stuck, just dont know why whats wrong or how to fix it

Comment: I did run it on alpine now  I dont know if I understand everything, the non RUN Commands give an error and all the run commands just execute reall quick and take me back to the cli except for the last line   && apk del git that seemed to throw an error

Comment: i did follow the answer below and the error seems to be from the first install git already

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding an additional line before using apk and see if it fixes

```
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules
RUN apk install git \
```

Reference: [link](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/55#issuecomment-135227655)

**Note**: Breaking the problematic step into multiple steps like

```
RUN apk install git
RUN npm i 
RUN apk del .gyp
RUN mv /var/app/node_modules /node_modules 
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* 
RUN apk del git
```

will help to locate the point of problem more accurately.

Comment: I just get stuck on the next step of RUN apk install git \

Comment: I ran it like that, and it seems to get an error from the first like of apk install git , I tried without that line and the apk del git lines and I get a bunch of error from the next step of npm i mostly it seems its trying to install deprecated modules, but at the end I also get a error that says git is missing

Comment: is there something wrong with the syntax of the apk install git command because at that point it gives me a bunch of syntax help like usage: apk COMMAND [-h|--help] [-p|--root DIR]

Comment: Please see if this solves the problem.
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/586#issue-273737852

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues. One is with the command `apk del .gyp` (which return code is different from `0`) , and the other is related to the fact that you do not mount correctly your folder.

```
# apk del .gyp
# echo $?
1
```

Besides, there is no such thing as `/var/app/node_modules` mounted in the container:

```
# ls /var/app/node_modules
# ls: /var/app/node_modules: No such file or directory
```

What you would do, is

1. Make sure you mount correctly `/var/app/node_modules` in the container
2. I am not sure what the command `apk del .gyp` is doing, but you may need to investigate it. It does not seems to work properly.

Comment: I assume apk del .gyp means to delete some file .gyp, I also am not sure what to mount since the app doesnt have a var/app directory and the node_modules directory is already in the root, so I deleted both lines and I was able to succesfully build an image, I dont know if not having one of those steps will mess something up though, also surprisingly the command RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*  does seem to go through so I dont know where it is finding that dir since I dont have a /var/ folder or a cache folder.

Comment: `npm i` will create the `node_modules` directory.  "Mounting" it isn't something that's possible here.

Comment: Yup I was able to get the image just taking out apk del .gyp and leaving the /var/app/node_modules command as is, any idea what that apk del .gyp is supposed to do or if its neccessary (should I worry about it?) it seems to me it wants to delete something so it shouldnt be a problem but not sure